# Panda Index Datetime Switching Months and Days

Tags: pandas, datetime, indexing, format

I have a panda df.index in the format below.

It's a string of day/month/year, so the first item is 05Sep2017 etc:

1. 05/09/17  #05Sep2017
2. 07/09/17  #07Sep2017
3. ...
4. 18/10/17  #18Oct2017

Applying

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

to the above, transforms it to:

1. 2017-05-09 #09May2017
2. 2017-07-09 #09Jul2017
3. ...
4. 2017-10-18 #18Oct2017

What seems to be happening is that the first entries are having the Day and Month switched. The last entry instead, where the day is greater than 12, is converted correctly.

I tried to switch month days by converting the index to a column and applying:

```
df['date'] = df.index
df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%d-%m'))
```

as well as:

```
df['date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but to no avail. 
How can i convert the index to datetime, where all entries are day/month/year please?

Comment: add dayfirst = True

Answer (score 0):

In pandas is default format of `date`s `YY-MM-DD`.

```
df = df.set_index('date_col')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print (df)
            val
2017-05-09    4
2017-07-09    8
2017-10-18    2

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-09', '2017-07-09', '2017-10-18'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

You need [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), but lost datetimes, because get strings:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
print (df.index)
Index(['2017-09-05', '2017-09-07', '2017-18-10'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
print (df)
             val
09-May-2017    4
09-Jul-2017    8
18-Oct-2017    2
```

Comment: The above yields:  'Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'.

Comment: maybe need first `df = df.set_index('date_col')`

Comment: last line is alternative, so use `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')` OR  `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%d-%b-%Y')`

Comment: Jezrael, thanks again.  I was getting stuck at the last line: "ValueError: month must be i in 1..12".  Then saw we can just add as argument      df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst = True) and the conversion worked properly.

Comment: Super, glad can help!